# How would I make the most recently posted in topic in a forum show up first?

Tags: php, html, date, time, forum

I am making a forum from one I borrowed online. I would like the main_forum page to show the most recently posted in topic first, and then the second most recently, etc. My code for the main_forum.php is this:

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/overall/header.php';
$sql="SELECT * FROM `forum_question` ORDER BY id DESC";
// OREDER BY id DESC is order result by descending
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<h1>Forum</h1>
<table width=700 class="outer">
<tr>
<td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Views</strong></td>
<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Replies</strong></td>
<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
// Start looping table row
if($result === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="view_topic.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['topic']; ?></a><BR></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['view']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['reply']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
// Exit looping and close connection 
}
mysql_close();
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="right" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><a href="create_topic.php"><strong>Create New Topic</strong> </a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
require_once 'includes/overall/footer.php';
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: It is impossible to answer without knowing the format of your database, but in your SQL just left join the forum_question table with the one containing the posts, order by the post date, and group by forum_question.id so it returns one row per forum.

Comment: I'll try to update my website with the PDO or MySQLi. Micheal, that mostly worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to retrieve your posts in the order you want them. Taking a guess based on your post I would say your query should look more like:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `forum_question` ORDER BY datetime DESC";
```